# Outlook causing table rows to overlap and get cut off

Tags: html, outlook, html-table, row, html-email

Does anyone have an idea what's causing this HTML email to display fine in all clients and browsers except for Outlook? The title gets cut off by the logo on top, and the social media icons are cut off beneath "Follow Us."

I've included the code specific to those rows:

```
<body width="100%" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="margin: 0; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">
<center style="width: 100%; background: #ffffff; text-align: left;"><!--
        Set the email width. Defined in two places:
        1. max-width for all clients except Desktop Windows Outlook, allowing the email to squish on narrow but never go wider than 600px.
        2. MSO tags for Desktop Windows Outlook enforce a 600px width.
    -->

<div class="email-container" style="max-width: 600px; margin: auto;"><!--[if mso]>
        <table role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="600" align="center">
        <tr>
        <td>
        <![endif]--><!-- Email Header : BEGIN -->

<tr>
    <td height="36" style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0; min-height: 36px !important;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<table align="center" aria-hidden="true" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="max-width: 600px;" width="100%">

    <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center" class=""><img alt="logo" aria-hidden="true" border="0" src="logo.jpg" style="display: block; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-width: 0px; border-style: solid; width: 181px; min-height: 45px; line-height: 1.4em;" height="45" width="181"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<tr>
    <td height="56" style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0; min-height: 56px !important;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>

<table aria-hidden="true" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" width="90%">
    <tr>
        <td height="43" style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0; min-height: 43px !important;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" class="stack-column-center" style="font-family: sans-serif; line-height: 1.4em; color: #777; padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px; overflow: hidden;">
        <h2 style="font-size: 15px; text-transform: uppercase; text-align: center;">Follow us</h2><br>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td height="27" style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0; min-height: 27px;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td align="center" class="stack-column-center" style="display: block; font-family: sans-serif; line-height: 1.4em; color: #777; padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px; min-height: 60px;">
        <a href="link"><img alt="LinkedIn social icon" aria-hidden="true" border="0" src="link" style="line-height: 1.4em; min-height: 29px; background: #fff; padding: 0 11px;" width="29" height="29"></a> <a href="link"><img alt="YouTube social icon" aria-hidden="true" border="0" src="link" style="min-height: 29px; background: #fff; padding: 0 11px;" width="29" height="29"></a> <a href="link"><img alt="Facebook social icon" aria-hidden="true" border="0" src="link" style="min-height: 29px; background: #fff; padding: 0 11px;" width="29" height="29"></a> <a href="link">
        <img alt="Twitter social icon" aria-hidden="true" border="0" src="linhk" style="min-height: 29px; background: #fff; padding: 0 11px;" width="29" height="29"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td height="43" style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0; min-height: 43px !important;">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is quiet a number of issues with your code. You had tr's starting without a table, div started but not closed and tables without a td or tr to sit under. I have made change changes to your html to fix the above, let me know if it works now.

```html
 <body width="100%" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="margin: 0; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">
 <center style="width: 100%; background: #ffffff; text-align: left;"><!--
 Set the email width. Defined in two places:
 1. max-width for all clients except Desktop Windows Outlook, allowing the email to squish on narrow but never go wider than 600px.
 2. MSO tags for Desktop Windows Outlook enforce a 600px width.
 -->

 <div class="email-container" style="max-width: 600px; margin: auto;"><!--[if mso]>
 <table role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="600" align="center">
 <tr>
 <td>
 <![endif]--><!-- Email Header : BEGIN -->
 <table align="center" aria-hidden="true" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="max-width: 600px;" width="100%">
 <tr>
 <td height="36" style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0; min-height: 36px !important;">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr><td>
 <table align="center" aria-hidden="true" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" role="presentation" style="max-width: 600px;" width="100%">

 <tr>
 <td style="text-align: center" class=""><img alt="BalanceWorks" aria-hidden="true" border="0" src="http://www2.eniweb.com/l/50342/2017-03-31/8dx33b/50342/153983/BalanceWorks_Transparent.jpg" style="display: block; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-width: 0px; border-style: solid; width: 181px; min-height: 45px; line-height: 1.4em;" height="45" width="181"></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </td></tr>
 <tr>
 <td height="56" style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0; min-height: 56px !important;">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr><td>
 <table width="90%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation">
 <tr>
 <td height="43" style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0; min-height: 43px !important;">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td align="center" class="stack-column-center" style="font-family: sans-serif; line-height: 1.4em; color: #777; padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px; overflow: hidden;">
 <h2 style="font-size: 15px; text-transform: uppercase; text-align: center;">Follow us</h2><br>
 </td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td height="27" style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0; min-height: 27px;">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 <tr><td align="center" class="stack-column-center" style="display: block; font-family: sans-serif; line-height: 1.4em; color: #777; padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px; min-height: 60px;">
 <a href="link"><img alt="LinkedIn social icon" aria-hidden="true" border="0" src="link/l/50342/2017-03-31/8dv136/50342/153855/linkedin.png" style="line-height: 1.4em; min-height: 29px; background: #fff; padding: 0 11px;" width="29" height="29"></a> <a href="link"><img alt="YouTube social icon" aria-hidden="true" border="0" src="link" style="min-height: 29px; background: #fff; padding: 0 11px;" width="29" height="29"></a> <a href="link"><img alt="Facebook social icon" aria-hidden="true" border="0" src="link" style="min-height: 29px; background: #fff; padding: 0 11px;" width="29" height="29"></a> <a href="link">
 <img alt="Twitter social icon" aria-hidden="true" border="0" src="linhk" style="min-height: 29px; background: #fff; padding: 0 11px;" width="29" height="29"></a></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td height="43" style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0; min-height: 43px !important;">&nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </td></tr></table></div>
 </body>
```

Cheers

Comment: Sorry. I only pasted the part of the code that wasn't working but I could have kept the parent elements. Thank you. It looks like changing em to px fixed it for me, but then your table align="center" fixed the alignment!